# PHP Regex missing capture group

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to parse several coordinates, but PHP preg_match is missing a capture group. It works in every regex simulator I've tested, but not in my code. Group 4 always comes up empty;

```
$coordinates = 'N40.765775°  E8.303369°';
// -40.765775°  -8.303369°
//  40.765775°  8.303369°
// -40.765775°  8.303369°
// N40.765775°  E8.303369°
// S40.765775°  E8.303369°
// N40.765775°  W8.303369°
// S40.765775°  W8.303369°

$regex = '/([-NnSs]?)\D*([0-9]?[0-9])\.(\d{1,10}+)\D\h*([-EeWw]?)\D*([0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])\.(\d{1,10}+)/';
if (preg_match($regex, $coordinates, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches);
} else {
    echo "no matches";
}
```

Comment: You can use `u` modifier as trincot said or change `\D` to `\S*`.

Comment: Not related to your problem: There are no characters between 0 and 1, you can write `[01]`, you don't need to use a range `[0-1]`. You also don't need to make the `\d{1,10}+` possessive since the first one is followed by `\D` and the second is at the end of the pattern, so `\d{1,10}`. Writing `[0-9][0-9]?` or `[0-9]{1,2}` reduces the number of steps needed than writing `[0-9]?[0-9]` when there's only one digit. You can also use the i modifier to ignore the case.

Comment: Does a coordinate values ever look like this: `N040.[the rest]`?  I am assuming not. Couldn't your leading/optional numeric range be more precise? `[1-9]?` and later in the pattern: `1?`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are parsing strings that have multibyte characters (°), you should add the unicode [modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), i.e. `u` at the end of the regex.

```
/      /u
```

Just as an illustration: without that modifier, if you would add a `.` after `\D`, here:

```
\D.\h*([-EeWw]?)
```

... then you would capture the "E" in the fourth capture group. So `\D.` actually matches the multibyte character `°`.